# Uploading a file in a specific path of an FTP server

Tags: java, ftp

I want to upload a file in a specific path in an ftp server the code is quite simple:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String server = "xx.xx.xx.xx";
String user = "xxx";
String pass = "xxx";

FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
try {

    ftpClient.connect(server);
    System.out.println("Connected to " + server + ".");
    System.out.print(ftpClient.getReplyString());

    ftpClient.login(user, pass);
    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

    ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

    // uploads first file using an InputStream
    File firstLocalFile = new File("/tmp/PAR.TXT");

    String firstRemoteFile = "/DATA/OUTFILES/PAR.TXT";
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(firstLocalFile);

    System.out.println("Start uploading first file");
    boolean done = ftpClient.storeFile(firstRemoteFile, inputStream);
    System.out.println("done:"+done);

    inputStream.close();
    if (done) {
        System.out.println("The file is uploaded successfully.");
    }


} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
            ftpClient.logout();
            ftpClient.disconnect();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

I always get done = false.

Here's the result:

```
Connected to xx.xx.xx.xx.
220 "Welcome (logging activated)"
Start uploading file
done:false
```

I printed the FtpClient#getReplyCode(). and i get this:

```
500 Illegal PORT command.
```

Comment: is the ftp server on windows or linux?

Comment: Can you upload the same file to the same folder using a GUI FTP client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I passed to PassiveMode and it works now

Comment: Just to clarify for other users, to enter the passive mode do this: 
    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

Answer (score 2):

You can only access files relative to the root folder of the ftp server. You need to configure your ftp server to add a virtual folder pointing to the path you want.